# Sticky Header jumps on scroll down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a strange problem . I wanted to build me a sticky head . On the internet I have found some instances also run, now I have so far implemented in my site. Now it is so that when I come through the peak , where the " fixed" position is set then the content jumps.

This is my javascript:

```
$(window).scroll(function()
{
  // This is the value from which the content (gridViewTop) should be sticked
  var objectheight = $('header').height();
  if( $(window).scrollTop() > objectheight )
  {
    $('#gridViewTop').css({position: 'fixed'});
    $('#gridViewTopPH').css({display: 'block'});
  } 
  else 
  {
    $('#gridViewTop').css({position: 'static', top: '0'});
    $('#gridViewTopPH').css({display: 'none'});
  }
});
```

One thing: i take the value (objectheight) because i want that on mobile devices too, and there it is possible that the user expand the menu and then the value is bigger then default.

(It is possible to use this on mobile devices?)

Here a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/vjb1ag27/

But i want a smove scrolling.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: It doesn't jump if you grab the scroll bar and slowly start scrolling down (WIN7/CHROME).   The only reason you're seeing a jump by mouse wheel (I'm guessing) is because the mouse-wheel scroll event in browsers isn't smooth - it jumps 5-10 lines with each tick/trigger.   See if get the same behavior by grabbing the scroll bar with the mouse and slowly scrolling down - looks smooth to me.

Comment: thanks for the response. i test it on mac/chrome and they are no mouse wheel jump (i know the trigger). i also have do it with the scroll bar, but there is the same problem.

Comment: looks fine, don't be obsessive!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, there's a little jump due to the margin applied to the *p* tag.

Therefore, when you call `if( $(window).scrollTop() >` **objectheight** is 40 pixels, but indeed there's a 10px gap that cause that jump.

You can either reduce the p margin via css or assign that margin value to **objectheight**.

http://jsfiddle.net/carlodurso/vjb1ag27/1/

Answer (score 0):

This might not work on mobile devices since the "scroll" event will only be fired once after scrolling stopped completely on the mobile device. So it will be a little 'jumpy'. What you need is a third-party library to handle scrolling events such as [iscroll](https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll)